# ¿Cómo actualizar un campo que su modelo tiene validación ? Api netCore

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, asp.net-core

Buenas estoy haciendo un CRUD y el problema que tengo es que cuando voy actualizar un solo campo por el método `PUT` utilizo el mismo modelo que tengo para el método `POST` este modelo tiene validaciones y al momento de hacer de invocar el método `PUT`. no me lo permite debido a que los otros campos tienen validaciones y deben ir allí

Modelo

```
public class BookShelfLine

{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 10, ErrorMessage = "Rango permitido 1-10")]
    public int Bookid { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 10, ErrorMessage = "Rango permitido 1-10")]
    public int Shelfid { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 50, ErrorMessage = "Rango permitido 1-50")]
    public int Avaliable { get; set; }
}
```

Controlador

```
    [Route("BookShelfLineInsert")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult BookShelfLineInsert(BookShelfLine bksl)
    {
        var MSJ = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
        
            string qry = @"INSERT INTO BookShelfLine (Bookid, Shelfid, Avaliable)
                           VALUES (@Bookid, @Shelfid, @Avaliable)";
            string conexion = _config.GetConnectionString("BibliotecaString");
            NpgsqlDataReader reader;
        
            using (NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(conexion))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(qry, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bookid", bksl.Bookid);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Shelfid", bksl.Shelfid);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Avaliable", bksl.Avaliable);
                    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    MSJ = (reader.RecordsAffected > 0) ? "ROWS AFFECTED" : "NO ROWS AFFECTED";
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MSJ = ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace;
        }

        return new JsonResult(MSJ);
    }

[HttpPut("{id}")]
    public IActionResult BookShelfLineUpdate(int id, BookShelfLine bSL)
    {
        var MSJ = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            string qry = @"UPDATE BookShelfLine SET shelfid = @shelfid   WHERE id = " + id +" ";
            string conexion = _config.GetConnectionString("BibliotecaString");
            NpgsqlDataReader reader;
       
            using (NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(conexion))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(qry, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Shelfid", bSL.Shelfid);
                    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    MSJ = (reader.RecordsAffected > 0) ? "ROWS AFFECTED" : "NO ROWS AFFECTED";
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MSJ = ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace; 
        }
        return new JsonResult(MSJ);
    }
```

Al utilizar Postman me arroja lo siguiente.

[image]

La solución mas fácil seria crear otro modelo con ese campo pero no es la solución que busco.

Atento a sus Comentarios

Comment: Creo que está bien reutilizar el mismo modelo, solo que si vas a hacer eso igual debes enviar toda la información del objeto para que no caiga en errores al momento de validarlo

Comment: Correcto mi intención era utilizar el mismo modelo para ambos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente no se debería de hacer de esa manera, pero si quieres seguir usando el mismo modelo, lo que puedes hacer es agregar valores por default a las propiedades, para que pase la validación en el método Put.

```
    public int Id { get; set; } = 1;

    [Range(1, 10, ErrorMessage = "Rango permitido 1-10")]
    public int Bookid { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 10, ErrorMessage = "Rango permitido 1-10")]
    public int Shelfid { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 50, ErrorMessage = "Rango permitido 1-50")]
    public int Avaliable { get; set; } = 1;
```

Comment: Gracias @TheOligarch, mas o menos había pensado algo así, pero no sabia como y era sumamente sencillo. Gracias por tu Respuesta

Comment: Al agregar valores por default el modelo siempre será válido y ya no tendría caso validarlo en el método POST. Básicamente con esto haces un fix al método PUT pero el POST ahora pierde sentido

Answer (score 0):

si solo quieres actualizar parcialmente una columna o propiedad de tu modelo, puedes utilizar el método PATCH, que se utiliza específicamente para eso, para actualizaciones parciales y no el PUT en el cual debes actualizar o mejor dicho enviar el objeto completo. Es UNA nota que también estaba repasando por estos días. Espero te ayude igual que a mi esta nota, es para tomar en cuenta. Saludos.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/365874)